# C/C++ Create an enum with negative values, without having to number it

Tags: c++, c, enums

For example in C/C++, I would have the code:

```
typedef enum fruits{
   apple,
   banana,
   lemon,
   orange
} fruit_t;
```

Which would be equivalent to:

```
typedef enum fruits{
   apple = 0,
   banana = 1,
   lemon = 2,
   orange = 3
} fruit_t;
```

However, I would like the values to be negative, so they do not conflict with anything else. I could do it like this:

```
typedef enum fruits{
   apple = -1,
   banana = -2,
   lemon = -3,
   orange = -4
} fruit_t;
```

But if I would like to add another fruit, I have to assign another value, and if I put one inbetween, I have to renumber most of it. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: You should use C++11 scoped enums. There's no such thing as C/C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Unless the intention is to write a definition that's usable in either language; in which case it's quite reasonable to call it "C/C++".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Start with `INT_MIN` on top like this:

```
#include <limits.h>

enum fruits
{
  orange = INT_MIN,
  lemon, 
  ...
}
```

Per "*5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types* " and/or "*Annex E/1*" of the C11 Standard `INT_MIN` is at least `-32767`.

`INT_MIN` gets defined by including `<limits.h>`.

Answer (score 19):

In *C* you only need to number the top one and subsequent entries will be the previous entry `+1`, this is covered in the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.7.2.2` *Enumeration specifiers* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> [...]An enumerator with = defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression. If the first enumerator has no =, the value of its enumeration constant is 0. **Each subsequent enumerator with no = defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant expression obtained by adding 1** to the value of the previous enumeration constant.[...]

and the wording is similar in the [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `7.2` *Enumeration declarations* paragraph *2*.

So just do something similar to the following:

```
#define MIN -4

typedef enum fruits{
   orange = MIN,
   lemon,  
   banana,
   apple,
} fruit_t;
```

Answer (score 10):

First of all, there is no such thing as "C/C++", those are two different languages.
You can't look at C as a subset of C++; some legal C code won't compile as a C++ program.

If you can use C++11, I suggest you use `enum class`, which gives you *strongly typed enumerations*:

```
enum class Traffic {red , yellow, green};
Traffic t = Traffic::red;

if ( t == Traffic::red )  // to test the value of an enum
```

This way you can guarantee no clashing, because the compiler won't let you do any comparison with an integer or with a variable of a different enum type.

You can only compare against a variable of the same enum type, or use the binary scope resolution operator as in the example.

Another advantage of this `enum class` is that you can set the size of your enum. You can use any signed or unsigned integer type like this:

```
enum class Traffic : char { red, yellow, green }
```

When a type is not specified, the default `int` is assumed.

Note that you need a compiler with C++11 support for this.

Answer (score 8):

Add news ones at the top.  You still have to number the topmost one.

```
enum fruit
{
   orange = -4,
   lemon,
   banana,
   apple,
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can order it anyway you like.

If you are not giving any value then next `enum` will take `+1` of its previous value. If even fist `enum` is not having any value then it will start from `0`.

But good practice is to have it in right order.

Answer (score 0):

It is also quite common to declare the errors as usual enumerations and
use the negative value of it, like:

```
typedef enum fruits_e {
    APPLE=1,
    BANANA,
    LEMON,
    ORANGE
} fruit_t;

fruit_t eat_fastfood(void) {
    if (! me->healthy())
        return -APPLE;
}
```

Comment: If a function returns an enum I would expect it to return values that actually are defined in the enum, so I can do `switch(eat_fastFood()) { case APPLE: case BANANA: case LEMON: case ORANGE: break; }` - I'd never expect needing to negate my cases (hopefully this is at least documented somewhere, else I would find out only by debugging or logging/printing the values after my program did not work as expected).